# Installing ESXi/ Hyper-V using NIC supporting iBFT

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, iscsi, nic

We can install ESXi to a iSCSI target if we have NIC that supports iBFT. But what I am trying to see is if we can install ESXi by booting off an iSCSI target which is a mounted ISO? How about Hyper-V ? If my understanding is correct, this requires installers to support Software iSCSI? Does ESXi/Hyper-V installer support Software iSCSI?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V boots in any way that Windows boots, including through iBFT.